# Hive UDF - Error in the evaluate() Method

Tags: java, hive, hive-udf

I created the following Java class and added it to Hive after making a jar out of it

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class MakeCap extends UDF{
  private Text t;

  public Text evaluate(Text input){
    if(null==input){
      t.set("Invalid input");
    }else{
      t.set(input.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
    return t;
  }
}
```

Next, I created a temporary function

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CAP AS 'com.iris.MakeCap';
```

But when I run

```
SELECT CAP('hello');
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''hello'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text com.iris.MakeCap.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text) 
with arguments {hello}:null (state=42000,code=10014)
```

I tried to use `String` instead of `Text` as the argument type for `evaluate()` but got the same result. Then I also tried this

```
SELECT CAP(e.name) FROM default.emp e;
```

and got the same error. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace Hadoop's `Text` type with simple Java's `String` type for both input and return. For `UDF` class it works fine. If you want to stick with `Text` I think you need to initialize your private variable `t`, e.g.

```
private final transient t = new Text()
```

Here is an [example code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFBase64.java) of Hive's UDF.